# Unique Associations From ActiveRecordRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many, relation

I have a `Project` model that `has-many` `People`.

Given an `ActiveRecordRelation` containing a large number of `Projects`, how can I efficiently get an `ActiveRecordRelation` containing all unique `People` associated with all the projects?

Basically I'm looking for an efficient way of doing:

```
@people = @projects.flat_map {|project| project.people}.uniq
```

Comment: did you try eager-loading the people relation? something like `Location.includes(:events).map(&:events).flatten.uniq`

Comment: @phoet. Doesn't seem to make a great deal of difference.

Comment: why? did you have a look the sql logs? which part is it that you want to speed up?

Comment: @phoet Yes. There is no marked improvement in query time.

Comment: well, that is surprisingly. my example produces just 2 sql calls, while i assume that your approach would do n+1 calls. or are you already eager loading the association?

Answer (score 1):

Eager loading does not appear to work correctly with `has_many`, or is not clever enough, at least. Rails will eager load the association, but then resort to a query when you call that relation on a specific instance.

Example (not actual queries):

```
@articles = Article.includes(:comments)
#> Article Load: SELECT * from articles
#> Comment Load: SELECT * from comments where article_id IN(1,2,3,4)

@articles.first.comments
#> Comment Load: SELECT * from comments where article_id IN(1)
```

In the `@articles.first.comments`, I would expect to see `Comment Load (Cache)` or something similar, as that comment has already been loaded.

There might be a better alternative, but I would simply perform a custom query such as:

`@people = People.where("project_id IN(?)", @projects.map(&:id))`

Rails 4:

`@people = People.where(project_id: @projects.map(&:id))`